# Binance: How to check BTC value by USDT at time of arrival after blockchain disabled it

Tags: exchange-rate, binance

Let's say that I received an amount of BTC to my Binance wallet one week ago.

How can I look up the value of the payment measured in USDT at the time I got paid?

I used to be able to see that on blockchain.com by looking up the transaction there, but they since removed the value by USDT at time of receiving.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: You find the value in USDT at time of arrival by hovering your mouse in blockchain.com.  Did you want to know how to use Binance's service to achieve this (which would be something you, as a customer, could ask them)? Or did you want to know something else?

Comment: Seems that you aren’t aware that blockchain disable the functionality of displaying the value at time of receive !

Comment: I wasn't aware, the question would be better with that information edited into it.